# print a pattern when line doesn't start with "#" in awk

Tags: awk

I'd like to print "chr" at the begin of each line that doesn't start with "#" in my file.

input :

```
##toto
#titi
16
17
```

output :

```
##toto
#titi
chr16
chr17
```

I've tried with awk (`awk '$1 ~ /^#/ ...` )  or grep (`grep "^[^#]" ...`) but got no success. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you're working with vcf files, remember to always use `awk -F'\t'` since there can be spaces in the INFO fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need `^[^#]` meaning, starting with a character that is not `#` and reconstruct those lines by prefixing with `"chr"`

```
awk '/^[^#]/{ $0 = "chr"$0 }1'
```

Comment: Or `!/^#/ { ... }` (but this matches empty lines too)

Comment: thanks ! I have a question , if i want  to print with the lign that start with "#" , what do I have to change in `awk '/^[^#]/` ?

Comment: @nstatam: You can do some trial and error to find that yourself. If `/^[^#]/` ignores lines starting with `#`, then do the opposite, remove the negation. as `/^#/`

Answer (score 3):

using `sed`

```
sed '/^#/! s/.*/chr&/'
```

Comment: `s/^/chr/` (doesn't need `.*`+`&`)

Comment: `sed 's/^[^#]/chr&/'` may be preferable to avoid adding the prefix to empty lines if any. Or `sed 's/^[[:digit:]]/chr&/'`

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk '{if(!/^#/ && !/^$/){$0="chr"$0;print}else if (/^#/ && !/^$/){print $0}}' filename
```

output

```
##toto
#titi
chr16
chr17
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'^#')
e=re.compile(r'^$')
p=open('filename','r')
for i in p:
    if not re.search(k,i)   and not re.search(e,i):
        print "chr{0}".format(i.strip())
    elif not re.search(e,i):
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
##toto
#titi
chr16
chr17
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know will correct it

Comment: Corrected and added the code